# AWK - processing matches before moving on to the next match

Tags: loops, shell, awk

i have a file that has multiple paragraphs that use brackets as separators like this

```
{
KEYWORD
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
}
{
d = 4
KEYWORD
e = 5
f = 6
}
```

I would like to loop over each paragraph and assign it to a variable $foo while perserving the line breaks so echo $foo will result in the paragraph being outputed in multi-line format. After processing the output of $foo e.g `echo $foo | grep bar` the program should go to the next paragraph and overwrite $foo

I have been playing with awk as it seems like the best tool in this case but i can't figure out how to do some sort of while loop so i can process each paragraph separately.

What I have so far is:

```
grep -Pzo "{[^}]*KEYWORD[^}]*}" FILENAME | awk "/{/{flag=1; 

paragraph=\"\"; next} /}/{flag=0; print paragraph} flag {paragraph = 

paragraph \$0 \"\\n\"}"
```

this produces neat paragraphs like this

```
KEYWORD
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

d = 4
KEYWORD
e = 5
f = 6
```

Where I am stuck is that I want to preform further actions on Paragraph 1 before moving on to Paragraph 2.

The closest I got to a solution was writing  the results to an array but then i lost the paragraph and everything was on one line and I couldn't do the post match processing I wanted.

**UPDATE:**

In the spirit of there is more than one way to do it and if you only have a hammer then everything looks like a nail I offer my solution:

```
# Read paragraphs into an array
while IFS= read -r paragraph; do
    paragraphs+=("$paragraph")
done < <(awk '/\{/{flag=1; paragraph=""; next} /\}/{flag=0; print paragraph} flag {paragraph = paragraph $0}' testoutput.txt)

# Print each paragraph separately
for ((i=0; i<${#paragraphs[@]}; i++)); do
    # Assign each paragraph to a variable using eval
    eval "foo_$i=\"${paragraphs[$i]}\""

    # Print the variable recreating the line breaks
    echo "Variable foo_$i:"
    eval "echo \"\$foo_$i\"|sed 's/\s\{2,\}/\n/g'"
done
```

The key to success was using sed `'s/\s\{2,\}/\n/g'` and not `\s` or `\s+` or one or more vs two or more.

Comment: Can `{` and `}` occur inside a single block that you want to extract as one entity? In other words: Is counting them necessary to capture the "right" ones?

Comment: @pmf I am not sure what you mean but the data is alway inside 1 {} block and there are no other brackets in that block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea using `mapfile` to read the 'paragraphs' into an array:

```
$ mapfile -d '}' paragraphs < data              # use '}' as our delimiter (instead of the default `\n`)

$ typeset -p paragraphs
declare -a paragraphs=([0]=$'{\nKEYWORD\na = 1\nb = 2\nc = 3\n}' [1]=$'\n{\nd = 4\nKEYWORD\ne = 5\nf = 6\n}' [2]=$'\n')
```

There are a few items of interest:

- array indices start at `0`
- we want to ignore the last array entry (index=`2`) as that captures everything after the last `}` in the file
- for the 2nd to nth 'paragraphs' there is a leading `\n` that we'll need to remove

Taking these issues into account ... one `bash/for` loop for processing one 'paragraph' at a time

```
for ((i=0; i<(${#paragraphs[@]}-1); i++))       # subtract 1 from number of array indices; in this case this gives us i<2
do
    echo "######### paragaphs[$i]"

    foo="${paragraphs[i]#$'\n'}"                # parameter substitution to remove a leading \n

    echo "${foo}"
done
```

This generates:

```
######### paragaphs[0]
{
KEYWORD
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
}
######### paragaphs[1]
{
d = 4
KEYWORD
e = 5
f = 6
}
```

**NOTE:** If the file is not formatted exactly as shown in the sample (eg, real file contains blank lines; there is extra white space before/after the  `{` and `}` characters, this may not work as expected and/or you may need to perform some additional [parameter substitutions](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) to massage `foo` into the desired format.

An example of some additional parameter substitutions to remove the `{\n` and `}\n`:

```
for ((i=0; i<(${#paragraphs[@]}-1); i++))
do
    echo "######### paragaphs[$i]"

    foo="${paragraphs[i]#$'\n'}"
    foo="${foo/$'{\n'}"
    foo="${foo/$'\n}'}"

    echo "${foo}"
done
```

This generates:

```
######### paragaphs[0]
KEYWORD
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
######### paragaphs[1]
d = 4
KEYWORD
e = 5
f = 6
```

Comment: All the answers worked but I felt that mapfile was the right tool for the job. I had read about it but on zsh with osx 14 I didn't have it readily available. brew bash fixed that. The code is both concise and readable.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach using a `while` loop over the lines of the input file. The lines are read by `read -r` into a variable `line`. If it's a `{`, reset the variable `foo`. If it's a `}`, do something with `$foo` (here, I'm printing its raw content, its length, and some static text). In any other case, append the contents of `line` to the current contents of `foo`.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

while read -r line; do
  case "$line" in
    '{') foo=;;
    '}') printf "Here's another foo:"
         printf '%s\n' "$foo"
         printf 'It has a length of %d.\n' "${#foo}";;
    *) foo="$(printf '%s\n' "$foo" "$line")";;
  esac
done < input.txt
```

```
Here's another foo:
KEYWORD
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
It has a length of 26.
Here's another foo:
d = 4
KEYWORD
e = 5
f = 6
It has a length of 26.
```

Answer (score 3):

Modifying OP's current `awk` script to generate each paragraph on a single line where embedded linefeeds (`\n`) are replaced by the literal characters `\` + `n`:

```
$ cat braces.awk
/{/   { flag = 1
        paragraph = ""
        next
      }
/}/   { flag = 0
        print paragraph
      }
flag  { paragraph = paragraph (paragraph ? "\\n" :"") $0 }
```

Running this against the sample input:

```
$ awk -f braces.awk data
KEYWORD\na = 1\nb = 2\nc = 3
d = 4\nKEYWORD\ne = 5\nf = 6
```

We can then feed these to `bash`s builtin `printf` to populate variable `foo`:

```
while read -r raw
do
    echo "############# ${raw}"

    printf -v foo "%b" "${raw}"

    echo "${foo}"
done < <(awk -f ./braces.awk data)
```

**NOTE:** `printf -v` requires `bash 3.1+`

This generates:

```
############# KEYWORD\na = 1\nb = 2\nc = 3
KEYWORD
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
############# d = 4\nKEYWORD\ne = 5\nf = 6
d = 4
KEYWORD
e = 5
f = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
count=(grep -c '}' file)
for ((i=2; i<=count+1; i++)); do
    foo="$(awk -v p=$i 'BEGIN{RS="{\n"} NR==p{print "{\n"$0}' file)"
done
```

The idea is to split output on the characters `{\n` to use multiline pattern in `awk`.

Comment: that prints the whole file. but even if it didn't i need to process each paragraph not just stop at one

Comment: Post edited accordingly to add the loop.